# Error to install zeromq in redhat 4.1

Tags: linux, redhat, zeromq

I can't install `zeromq` on my  machine 
my machine is redhat 4.1
this is the error message:

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/data/vvlog/zeromq-3.2.0/src'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/data/vvlog/zeromq-3.2.0/src'
if /bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CXX --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I.   -pedantic -Werror -Wall -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE  -DZMQ_FORCE_EPOLL -fvisibility=hidden  -g -O2 -MT libzmq_la-address.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/libzmq_la-address.Tpo" -c -o libzmq_la-address.lo `test -f 'address.cpp' || echo './'`address.cpp; \
    then mv -f ".deps/libzmq_la-address.Tpo" ".deps/libzmq_la-address.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/libzmq_la-address.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
../libtool: line 869: X--tag=CXX: command not found
../libtool: line 902: libtool: ignoring unknown tag : command not found
../libtool: line 869: X--mode=compile: command not found
../libtool: line 1035: *** Warning: inferring the mode of operation is deprecated.: command not found
../libtool: line 1036: *** Future versions of Libtool will require --mode=MODE be specified.: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: Xg++: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-DHAVE_CONFIG_H: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-I.: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-I.: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-I.: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-pedantic: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-Werror: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-Wall: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-D_GNU_SOURCE: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-D_REENTRANT: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-D_THREAD_SAFE: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-DZMQ_FORCE_EPOLL: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-fvisibility=hidden: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-g: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-O2: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-MT: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: Xlibzmq_la-address.lo: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-MD: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-MP: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X-MF: command not found
../libtool: line 1179: X.deps/libzmq_la-address.Tpo: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1179: X-c: command not found
../libtool: line 1231: Xlibzmq_la-address.lo: command not found
../libtool: line 1236: libtool: compile: cannot determine name of library object from `': command not found
make[2]: *** [libzmq_la-address.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/data/vvlog/zeromq-3.2.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/vvlog/zeromq-3.2.0/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some [docs](http://blog.serverdensity.com/building-zeromq-and-pyzmq-on-red-hat/) on installing 0MQ on redhat

Comment: i have installed the requirements accordance with the instructions above ,and can't install zeromq too

Comment: Are you attempting to install via Yum pkg or from src? Also, make sure your autoconf pkg is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same situation on my own c++ source.  The reason was version compatibility issue between new libtool and old ltmain.sh. [What is ltmain.sh, and why does automake say it is missing? What is a good auto (make/conf/etc) generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807915/what-is-ltmain-sh-and-why-does-automake-say-it-is-missing-what-is-a-good-auto) page shows the detail and how to regenerate ltmain.sh.